# Pandas: How do you get column labels from one df based on row values and assign these as row values in new df?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df_1` with the following structure:

```
df_1:

    fruit_group_a   fruit_group_b
0   apple           banana
1   orange          pineapple
```

Given a string value such as `apple` or `orange` in `df_2`:

```
df_2:

    fruit
0   apple
1   pineapple
2   orange
3   banana
```

I want to use the information in dataframe `df_1` to assign the corresponding fruit group name in a separate column to get the desired output `df_3` as follows:

```
df_3:

    fruit           fruitgroup
0   apple           fruit_group_a
1   pineapple       fruit_group_b
2   orange          fruit_group_a
3   banana          fruit_group_b
```

How do I accomplish this? (I should mention that the dataframes in the real use case has 50+ columns and several hundred rows)

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), then [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join - if no match get missing values:

```
df = df_2.merge(df_1.melt(var_name='fruitgroup', value_name='fruit'), how='left')
print (df)
       fruit     fruitgroup
0      apple  fruit_group_a
1  pineapple  fruit_group_b
2     orange  fruit_group_a
3     banana  fruit_group_b
```

---

```
print (df_2)
       fruit
0      apple
1  pineapple
2     orange
3       pear

df = df_2.merge(df_1.melt(var_name='fruitgroup', value_name='fruit'), how='left')
print (df)
       fruit     fruitgroup
0      apple  fruit_group_a
1  pineapple  fruit_group_b
2     orange  fruit_group_a
3       pear            NaN
```

Without left join:

```
df_3 = df_2.merge(df_1.melt(var_name='fruitgroup', value_name='fruit'))
print (df_3)
       fruit     fruitgroup
0      apple  fruit_group_a
1  pineapple  fruit_group_b
2     orange  fruit_group_a
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df_3 = df_2.merge(df_1.melt(var_name='fruitgroup', value_name='fruit'))
```

output:

```
       fruit     fruitgroup
0      apple  fruit_group_a
1  pineapple  fruit_group_b
2     orange  fruit_group_a
3     banana  fruit_group_b
```

intermediate output of `melt`:

```
df_1.melt(var_name='fruit_group', value_name='fruit')

     fruit_group      fruit
0  fruit_group_a      apple
1  fruit_group_a     orange
2  fruit_group_b     banana
3  fruit_group_b  pineapple
```